# OpenShift 3 Starter plan does not sleep from inactivity

Tags: openshift

I'm trying out OpenShift Starter plan and I'm just a little confused about the Resource Hibernation.  It states that for the free plan:

> Your project resources sleep after 30 minutes of inactivity, and must sleep 18 hours in a 72 hour period

I have 2 projects running (1 pod each) and I've yet to see the pods come down from inactivity, even after hours of no network traffic.

Am I mis-understanding the limitation?  And is there some way I can tell how long a pod's been sleeping to make sure I don't exceeded the 18 hour sleep in 72 hour period?  I have no need for the app to be up over night so I can easily meet that requirement, but it doesn't appear to sleep with inactivity.

Comment: If you have any probes running, those are technically counted as traffic. But you don't need to worry about enforcing the pod sleeping yourself. It'll still get removed regardless 60 days after signing up, and then you can just sign up again!

Comment: I did not add any liveness/readiness probes so it wouldn't be that.  The 1 app I could see having a lot of background traffic but the other is just a simple "hello-world" spring-boot app that does nothing but serve up a single jsp.